# Double integral related to exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function, improper-integrals

I found the following bivariate integral and I do not know how to attack it.
$$ \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-f(x,y)} \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \, \partial y} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y,$$
where $f:\mathbb{R^{+}}\times\mathbb{R^{+}} \mapsto \mathbb{R^{+}}$ is differentiable infinitely many times. Moreover I know that for any $y \in [0,\infty)$, $\lim_{x\mapsto \infty} f(x,y) = 0$, for any $x \in [0,\infty)$, $\lim_{y\mapsto \infty} f(x,y) = 0$ and that the integral exists finite.

Do you have some technique to suggest to attack this kind of integral or similar bivariate integrals?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-f(x,y)} \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \, \partial y} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y = \int_0^\infty \left( \frac \partial {\partial y} \int_0^\infty e^{-f(x,y)} \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} \, \mathrm{d}x \right) \, \mathrm{d}y
$$
According to Theorem 2 on [this page](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jyang06/stat411/handouts/InterchangeDiffandIntegral.pdf), the equality above is valid if $\dfrac {\partial f} {\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\, \partial x}$ are both continous. Or at least that is true if one integrates over a bounded interval, so you may want to do a bit of work with limits as something approaches $+\infty.$

This makes the inner integral into $\displaystyle\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} e^{-u} \, du $ where $a(y) = f(0,y)$ and $b(y)=f(\infty,y) = \lim\limits_{u\,\to\,+\infty} f(u,y).$ Then think about [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: thanks @MichealHardy. I do not understand how to obtain the eqaulity applying Theorem 2. What I understood is that Theorem 2 allow us to interchange integral and derivative, but we have also $e^{-f(x,y)}$ inside the integral and before the derivative. So I do not see how to justify the equality even if the continuity assumptions hold.